# Transaction is not rolled back in JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I have a code that is very similar to this one:

```
dslContext.transaction(new TransactionalRunnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run(Configuration arg0) throws Exception
    {
        dao1.insert(object1);
        //Object 1 is inserted in the database 
        //despite the exception that is being thrown
        if(true)
           throw new RuntimeException();
        dao2.insert(object2)
    }
});
```

This is the code I'm using to create the dsl context and the daos that have been generated with JOOQ.

```
ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
comboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getName());
comboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database?searchpath=schema");
comboPooledDataSource.setUser("user");
comboPooledDataSource.setPassword("password");
comboPooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
comboPooledDataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(25);
Configuration configuration=new DefaultConfiguration().set(comboPooledDataSource).set(
                        SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
DSLContext dslContext=DSL.using(configuration);
Dao1 dao1=new Dao1(configuration);
Dao2 dao2=new Dao2(configuration);
```

Why am I getting this behavior?

Comment: `I have a code that is very similar to this one:`, and when you run the posted code, you have the same behaviour ?

Comment: What jOOQ version are you using? Can you show how your `comboPooledDataSource` is configured?

Comment: @LukasEder I'm using version 3.9.1 of JOOQ and I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your `DAO`s are configured with a different configuration than your transaction. This means that each DAO runs its code in a new auto-committed transaction, even if you put that logic inside of a `TransactionalRunnable`.

This would work:

```
dslContext.transaction(new TransactionalRunnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run(Configuration arg0) throws Exception
    {
        new Dao1(arg0).insert(object1);
        if(true)
           throw new RuntimeException();
        new Dao2(arg0).insert(object2)
    }
});
```

Note that [`DSLContext.transaction(TransactionalRunnable][1])` does not modify the `dslContext` and its enclosed `Configuration`. This means that if your data source is not working e.g. like a JavaEE or Spring [`TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html), then you *must* use the argument `Configuration` of your `run()` method to run further queries, either by wrapping it with `DSL.using(configuration)` or by passing it to your daos.

A much simpler option would be to use a data source that is transaction aware (i.e. it binds a transaction to a thread), such that the same thread will always get the same transacted JDBC `Connection` from the datasource.

Answer (score 2):

I'm letting spring handle the transactions with jOOQ. Here is how:

This is the spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException
    {
        comboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getName());
        comboPooledDataSource
                    .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database?searchpath=schema");
        comboPooledDataSource.setUser("databaseuser");
        comboPooledDataSource.setPassword("password");

        comboPooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
        comboPooledDataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        comboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        return comboPooledDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException
    {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException
    {
        return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() throws PropertyVetoException
    {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(transactionAwareDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public org.jooq.Configuration configuration() throws PropertyVetoException
    {
        return new DefaultConfiguration().set(connectionProvider()).set(transactionProvider()).set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionProvider transactionProvider() throws PropertyVetoException
    {
        return new SpringTransactionProvider(transactionManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public DSLContext dslContext() throws PropertyVetoException
    {
        return DSL.using(configuration());
    }
}
```

And this is the `SpringTransactionProvider`:

```
public class SpringTransactionProvider implements TransactionProvider
{
    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public SpringTransactionProvider(DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager)
    {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(TransactionContext ctx)
    {
        TransactionStatus tx = transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition(
                TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED));
        ctx.transaction(new SpringTransaction(tx));
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(TransactionContext ctx)
    {
        transactionManager.commit(((SpringTransaction) ctx.transaction()).tx);
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback(TransactionContext ctx)
    {
        transactionManager.rollback(((SpringTransaction) ctx.transaction()).tx);
    }

    class SpringTransaction implements Transaction
    {
        final TransactionStatus tx;

        SpringTransaction(TransactionStatus tx)
        {
            this.tx = tx;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally to get the `DSLContext`:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
DSLContext dslContext=applicationContext.getBean(DSLContext.class);
```

You will need those jars in your classpath to get this to work: 
`spring-tx.jar`, `spring-aop.jar`, `spring-expression.jar`, `spring-core.jar`, `spring-beans.jar`, `spring-jdbc.jar` and `spring-context.jar` :)